# how to update and append values to array in google spanner

Tags: sql, arrays, google-cloud-platform, sql-update, google-cloud-spanner

I have a column with data type Array(String) in spanner. How can I append value to an array for update queries

I'm able to update the values using this command

```
update CarTable set models = ["BMW","HONDA"] WHERE year = "2020"
```

But the problem with this update is it overrides the previous values. I want to append these values to the ones that are already present. Is there any command that takes care of this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ARRAY_CONCAT`](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_concat) function for that:

```sql
update CarTable set models = ARRAY_CONCAT(models, ["BMW","HONDA"]) WHERE year = "2020"
```